# Serialization Attributes in C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, attributes, element

Which of the following are valid XML Serialization Attributes in C#:

1. XMLAttribute
2. XMLElement
3. XMLElementName
4. XMLRootElement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e(v=vs.110).aspx

1 and 2 are the only valid attributes that you listed.

Comment: Shane : The list is not complete.  For example the following is valid :     [XmlRoot(ElementName = "abc")]

Comment: @jdweng the code you specified is valid, but I am not sure why you claim the list is not complete.  `XmlRoot` is listed in the link I provided.  `ElementName` is a property of the `XmlRoot` attribute...

Comment: The link has XmlRootAttribute not XmlRoot.  And the link doesn't show the property name which I thought should be given.

Comment: @jdweng the `Attribute` part of the name is common for .NET attributes even though it is not used when actually decorating a class with the attribute.  If you click on the attribute name that provides you with more information including the properties.

Comment: @ShaneRay Thanks! And just to be sure, as ElementName is a property of the XmlRoot attribute, it is not a valid attribute, right?